# How solve an Increase function problem

Tags: calculus, functions

I was trying to figure out to solve this question. I understand getting increases and decrease after getting the derivatives based on what I've learned, I am stuck and don't understand how to solve this math problem below.

If $f(t)=t^2 + t$, Between $t = 10$ and $t = 12$, what is the increase in f divided by the increase in t?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

The question is asking you to calculate $$\frac{f(12)-f(10)}{12-10}$$

Where the numerator shows the difference in $f$, and the denominator the difference in $t$.

Comment: Is it me or is the question somewhat vague? Since it mentions increase, I understood I had to look for where the derivative was increasing or decreasing.

Comment: The function is increasing across that range.

Answer (score 1):

$\frac{f(12)-f(10)}{12-10}=\frac{156-110}{2}=\frac{46}{2}=23$